# Excel Macro to clear cells after 4 months AND when another cell is filled in

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with a list where I need to automatically clear data in column G-I if two criteria are true:

1. If column N has a value

AND

2. If column A is older than 4 months

I've been googling and reading up, and found something that I think might be on the right track, using the `If DateDiff` code, but I have no idea how to adjust the code to be matching per row and also take into account that column N needs to be filled in.

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N6:N2000")) Is Nothing Then

  If DateDiff("d", FileDateTime(ThisWorkbook.FullName), Now) >= 120 Then
  ' this above needs to only check on cell at the time in A??? 

        Target.Offset(0, -5).ClearContents
        Target.Offset(0, -6).ClearContents
        Target.Offset(0, -7).ClearContents

    ThisWorkbook.Save
  End If
 End If
End Sub
```

Am I getting close?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are kind of close, but honestly, in VBA there are different ways of doing stuff. About your question, I think it would be better if you loop trough all the usedcells, checking A and N, and deleting (or not) the row.

Comment: Thanks foxfire. Cant delete the whole row. The data needs to be stored, but GDPR means personal info needs to be deleted once the information is no longer important. So I cant remove the whole row.

But - if I get a code to loop to check A and N, cant I instead of creating a delete-commando use my offset-commando?

Comment: My bad. In your question you typed **...clear data in column G-I...**. It would be the same but just clearing contents of range `Gx:Ix` where `x` would be the row number being checked in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a solution:

```
Sub ClearCells()
  Dim Cel As Range, Ws As Worksheet
   Set Ws = Sheets("NameOfSheet")
     For Each Cel In Ws.Range("A6", Ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
     If DateDiff("d", Cel, Date) > 120 And Cel.Offset(, 13) <> "" Then 
     Cel.Offset(, 6).Resize(, 3).ClearContents
    Next Cel
End Sub
```